# How do I filter models from the Django admin sidebar while keeping them on their children's change page form?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a setup that looks like this: [image]

Because 'Charities' and 'Interventions' aren't meant to be edited except from the Evaluations and Max Impact Fund Grants page, I don't want to show up in the navbar menu. I've been scraping through the bowels of Django looking for a way to do this, and the *least* hacky way I can find is overwriting the django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.get_app_list function, such that after it's assembled the app_list array, I modify in place the element containing the models to delete the offending two.

The two problems with this are 1) it's incredibly hacky and 2) it doesn't actually work - I end up with an empty navbar with the message that I don't have permission to modify any objects (I confirmed that the app_list post-modification had the rest of the elements).

I feel like there's probably some trivial approach like 'define the app_navbar_models variable to have an exclude list on one of your admin objects', but I have failed to find such an approach either on StackOverflow or indicated in the Django code. Did I miss something?

Comment: Have you tried to [`unregister`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2bee0b4328319eaf6a0d1686677d629f2ecf6dec/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L151) your models in the `admin.py` file? As simple as `admin.site.unregister(Charities)`, `admin.site.unregister(Interventions)`.
Also I would recommend not registering models to in `admin.py` if you don't want them to be editable in the admin site.

Comment: @mtzd I tried not registering them, but then they can't be edited or created from the Evaluations or Max Impact Fund Grant change forms, which I *do* need them to be able to do.